# Stripping null bytes from a unicode string

Tags: c#

My paths are UTF-16 strings. Most of them only use the ASCII set, so a filename like `test` would be stored as

```
T \x00 E \x00 S \x00 T \x00
```

I use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)` to read the string and it works fine (when I print them out to console or to a form control it appears as I expect), but when I want to actually create a file with the given filename using the following code

```
BinaryWriter outFile = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
```

I get an exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
```

It's probably because there are null chars in there (maybe it stores the original byte array internally), but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Not all of the strings are ASCII though, and some of the characters use two-bytes.

UPDATE:

Turns out the illegal bytes were simply null bytes that were padded to the string. However, I can't simply strip all trailing null bytes, but I don't know the length of the string either. How would I strip null bytes from a string where each character is stored in n bytes?

Comment: It doesn't store a byte array internally. I suggest you *really* diagnose the contents of `path` by dumping the length and the content, character by character, including the Unicode integer value of each character.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that. Printed out the length of the string, and turns out it's not automatically stripping all of the padded null chars (the filenames were padded to 256 bytes). What is a correct way to remove null bytes in a UTF-16 string? I don't think I should just strip off every \x00.

Comment: A common situation where you have trailing nul bytes in a buffer is if you get the buffer from a `MemoryStream` and use `GetBuffer()` instead of `ToArray()` to retrieve the bytes in the stream.

Comment: @Keikoku: If the string is UTF-16 encoded you have to examine each 16 bit word in the string. The first 16 bit word that is 0 is the nul terminator.

Comment: Another common reason for trailing zero bytes is when reading data using the `Stream.Read` method, and ignoring the return value which contains the number of actual bytes that was placed in the buffer.

Comment: Are you sure the string is encoded in UTF-16? One way to get result you are describing is to try to decode a UTF-32 encoding as UTF-16.

Comment: Each ASCII character is encoded in two bytes, so I assume it is UTF-16 encoding. Plus the strings print out to console correctly (there are some japanese strings mixed in there) so I'm convinced it is UTF-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the MSDN on `Path.GetInvalidPathChars'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx)

> The full set of invalid characters can vary by file system. For
>   example, on Windows-based desktop platforms, invalid path characters
>   might include ASCII/Unicode characters 1 through 31, as well as quote
>   ("), less than (<), greater than (>), pipe (|), backspace (\b), null
>   (\0) and tab (\t).

You could use `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` as a filter. Copy your input string to an output string while filtering any characters that match a character from `Path.CheckInvalidPathChars`.

Here's an example I cooked up:

```
string input = @"This <path> ""contains"" |some| ~invalid~ characters";

var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();

string output = input.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => invalidChars.Contains(c) ? sb : sb.Append(c), sb => sb.ToString());

// output contains: This path contains some ~invalid~ characters
```

Note that most symbols are filtered out, but the tildes are not, since they are valid path characters.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error most likely because your path contains one of the invalid characters that are available if you call `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`.

Some of these chars are `"`, `<`, `|` and `>`.

Because you have already decoded the string by using `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` this problem is not related to any UNICODE encoding issues.

Here is some simple (but not very efficient) code to replace invalid characters in a path with underscore:

```
var stringBuilder = path
  .Select(c => Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Contains(c) ? '_' : c)
  .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, c) => a.Append(c));
path = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: I figured that might be the case. How can I deal with it without changing how the filenames appear to the user?

Comment: @Keikoku: It is up to you. You could replace invalid characters by underscore or encode them using some sort of hexadecimal notation. It depends on how you expect to use the file names. You also need to handle collisions in some way.